# Android Studio - image source issue

Tags: android, imageview, rendering

I have created folder called "activity_informations" in default drawable folder:

[image]

Now I want to add attribute `android:src` to `ImageView`:

```
android:src="@drawable/activity_informations/happy_face"
```

but program signals rendering problem:

```
Failed to convert @drawable/activity_informations/happy_face into a drawable
```

How I could solve this?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Remove the sub folder activity_information inside drawable folder

Comment: But I want to better organise my image files using subfolder. Is it wrong or 
impossible?

Comment: you can´t create subfolders inside the drawables directory, it´s restricted in android